# socat bidirectional forwarding between UART and TCP (RPi)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, bidirectional, piping, socat

Hey Guys i'm looking for some help with socat, it is very complicated to my beginner knowledge.

Some background, i have a device connect by uart (/dev/ttyS0) to my RPi and communication between them work great!

Now, i want the SAME information that is being received on ttyS0 to go via ethernet connection to a "transmitter / receiver" (one device), AND what ever information is received by the receiver to go into the RPi (via ethernet) and go through the uart (/dev/ttyS0) into the final component.

I have tried a few options with socat, but i can not seem to get the code of line to work.

i have the ip of the tx/rx and its port number, just asking how to implement them

code ive tried:
`sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw tcp:192.168.19.240:23&`
and when i type it in, i notice that i lose connection on my serial to the original device "link 1 down"

im running:
`mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyS0` and once i run the above socat command in a different terminal, in the first terminal that i ran Mavproxy, i get the `link 1 down`.

with Mavproxy i have the option to add --out=udp:(IP):port, could i perhaps use this? and maybe socat in unidirectional back to uart?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be good if you could describe and/or demonstrate what you tried already. That way, others could understand much better what exactly you need. Like this, the question is probably too broad.

Comment: ive tried this line:
'sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw tcp:192.168.19.240:23&'
without really knowing alot, but what i have seen, is when i link the /dev/ttyS0 i lose connection with the monitor that initiated the connection